# Sieve of Eratosthenes execution time in haskell

Tags: performance, haskell, functional-programming, execution-time, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am newbie in Haskell and was writing code for solving the Sieve of Eratosthenes problem using lists. Here is the code

```
primes m = 2 : primes' m [3,5 ..m] [] where
primes' m integers@(p : xs) acc   | p*p>m =  reverse acc ++ integers
                                  | True  = primes' m (xs `remove` [p*p, p*p+2*p..m]) (p:acc)

remove integers@(x:xs) multiples@(y:ys) | x < y = x : remove xs multiples
                                        | x == y =    remove xs ys
                                        | x > y =     remove integers ys

remove integers multiples = integers
```

If I input m = 2000000, the code takes around 14 seconds to print out all the results. I think 90 percent of the time goes to printing and not actually executing the code. Is there a way to find the correct execution time for this particular program?

Comment: I'm no Haskell expert, but your `remove` looks like it has to go through all of the unremoved numbers. A real sieve of Eratosthenes gets to jump right to the flags for the numbers it's marking composite, which is a lot faster. Rule of thumb: if there's no array of boolean flags, it's probably not really a sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: @user2357112 that's debatable. I think the essence of SoE is its generation of composites from each prime by repeated increment. how these multiples are then skipped over is a matter of a specific implementation. OP's `remove` is `Data.List.Ordered.minus`. of course arrays have advantage of random access, but an implementation with ordered lists can be had for just an additional log factor in the complexity. more [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers).

Comment: `remove` does go through all the numbers, but the iteration is stopped early, at the sqrt of the top limit. so overall it's roughly `primesTo m = foldl minus [3,5..] [[p*p, p*p+2*p..m] | p <- takeWhile ((<= m) . (^2)) primes]`. Which as Melissa O'Neill shows in her JFP paper has complexity just above n^1.5.

Comment: @WillNess: Despite performing the same repeated increments as the SoE, I would consider this algorithm much closer to trial division, as it needs to consider each number once for every prime up to its first divisor instead of once for every prime divisor. Melissa O'Neill also seems to feel strongly that performing increments instead of division doesn't turn trial division into the SoE in [the paper](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf) I think you're referring to. (Also, wow, you've edited that wiki page 550 times over the course of a decade.)

Comment: That said, I don't consider the flag array strictly necessary for a sieve of Eratosthenes, but for the kind of code people write on their first attempt at a sieve, the rule of thumb works pretty well.

Comment: that paper was very confusing for me, except for the math in it. here of course there's no trial divisions. if this foldl-based code `(...(((xs -a)-b)-c)-...)` is turned into foldr-based one `(xs -(a+(b+(c+...))))`, and if, further, the sum is found as a tree, not as a list, the complexity is just one `log N` factor worse than the random-access sieve (same as PQ-based one in the paper, btw). Eratosthenes himself counted by 1s, for all we know. :) here at least each enumeration *directly* finds each next multiple by adding `2*p`, not adding `1` _2p_ times. So I do consider it the true sieve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173533/discussion-between-will-ness-and-user2357112).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it with

```
main = print $ last $ primes 2000000
```

so it'll show you only the last found prime.

Compile it with `-O2` and run with `+RTS -s` to see the overall timings and the memory stats.

Be sure to measure it at several size points, to find out the [empirical orders of growth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth)! True sieves run at about `~ n^1.1`, in *n* primes produced. Anything up to `~ n^1.5` is passable. `~ n^2` is bad, any slower than that is even worse. :)

Yours should be all right, by the looks of it.